# How to configure auto completion in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why does VS Code code completion dropdown menu includes my personal files and even browser history? How to restrict completion to code related stuff?

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.